# Can we use Ethereum Swarm to store normal data other than blockchain or dapp data.

Tags: ether, storage, hash, swarm, decentralization

I want some basic data to be stored like name and city phone no etc.So just want to ask can I use ethereum swarm just to store file and make several node to create decentralized storage.